# Add 'video not supported' message to Rails video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html5-video

Is there any way to made this code working?

```
= video_tag("#{video.mp4}", "#{video.ogv}", 'Your browser does not support the video tag.'
```

Now it only adds new video source with text message instead of returning it like that:

```
<video>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You'll need to render this on your own in the template:

```
<video>
  <source src="#{movie.mp4}" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="#{movie.ogg}" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Or build a helper which does that for you:

```
def video_tag_with_not_supported_text(*sources)
  options = sources.extract_options!.symbolize_keys
  sources.flatten!

  content_tag(:video, options) do
    safe_join (
      sources.map { |source| tag('source', :src => path_to_video(source)) } +
      ['Your browser does not support the video tag.']
    )
  end
end
```

and then use it like:

```
=video_tag_with_not_supported_text('/x.mp4', '/y.ogv', width: '800px')
```